# Lose the connection to WildFly after restarting MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, ejb, wildfly

After restarting MySQL loses the WildFly connection. We used 2 versions MySQL, MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.51, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrappe and MySQL Ver 8.0.28 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

We tried on 2 versions of Wildfly `wildfly-10.1.0.Final` and `wildfly-19.1.0.Final` and we used JDBC a database connector version is - 8.0.19

```java
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("returning new connection");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false", "xxxx", "xxxx");
        return con;
    }
```

How can we reconnect automatically after restarting MySQL server, what is the best approach?

We're getting error messages

```java
1. 2022-04-08 16:09:36,614 ERROR [xxx.xxx.mysql.MysqlSentSMSDAo] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9) No operations allowed after connection closed.: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1575)
    at xxx.xxxx.loader.mysql.MysqlSentSMSDAo.selectReplyRecord(MysqlSentSMSDAo.java:85)
    at xxx.xxx.loader.schedular.UpdateReplyReport.execute(UpdateReplyReport.java:109)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:1171)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:576)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1590)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

2. The last packet successfully received from the server was 4,742 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 4,744 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at xxx.xxx.loader.mysql.MysqlSentSMSDAo.getListOfSQLSentSMSEntities(MysqlSentSMSDAo.java:39)
    at xxx.xxx.loader.schedular.UpdateBulkReceipts.execute(UpdateBulkReceipts.java:59)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: This looks like code from 20+ years ago.  Wildfly has a built in connection pooling mechanism and one part of that is the ability to validate the connection before it's given out.  Are you getting any exceptions or logs that expand on the issue?

Comment: @stdunbar, I included error messages now can you please advise me

Comment: This shows that the Connection is closed already.  Your code is very simplistic and you must be keeping the Connection even if it's no longer valid.  You can call `connection.isClosed()` before using the connection.  But, again, you're doing this the hard way - use the built in connection pool.  You cannot reuse the Connection that has been closed.  You must get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Add property **autoReconnect=true** in the connection string, which makes the connection to auto recover. If you are using Wildfly, then better to define data source in standalone.xml, with **autoReconnect=true** in <connection-url> tag.

.